# How to make rest of background darker when you click on an image and it pops out

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey so im currently making a website and i have pictures set up so when you click on them they get bigger and go into the center of the page. This works fine but im trying to make the rest of the webpage (besides the big picture) go a bit darker.

An example of this is if you open up a facebook picture and you can see the rest of the page turns black and the opacity is about 0.5

This is the some of the code i have for the function in jquery

```
$(this).click(function(evt){
                    $("#bigimg").attr("src", imageURL);
                    $("#bigimg").attr("style", "display:block");

                    evt.preventDefault();

                    $('body').css('opacity', '0.5');
                    $('#bigimg').css('opacity', '1');

                });
```

When i run this the whole web page goes to 0.5 opacity when i want the picture (#bigimg) to stay as bright as it normally is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a backdrop instead of changing the body opacity.  The popup IS part of the body, and will assume the opacity change.  Even better, use http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0):

applying the opacity to the body applies it to everything in it. you need to create a div with your desired opacity and add it to your body, then add your image with a higher z-index

```
var mask = $('<div class="bgmask"></div>');
$('body').append(mask);
```

the css:

```
.bgmask {
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 100;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: might need a body, html {width: 100%; height: 100%;}